# Javascript append an element to Array at specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dynamically generated Array:

```
myArr = ["val0a", "val1a", "val2a"... "val600a"]
```

I am having problems appending a new array values to this array in a loop. My Array should look like this after the append:

```
myArr = ["val0a", "val1a val1b", "val2a val2b"... "val600a"]
```

Please note that the new array and the old one do not have the same length.

How can I do this? It have to be something simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I'm confused - you want to append to the array (per your question title), or append to an element *in* the array, per your example

Comment: append to an element in the array. I probably need to fix my title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a function along the lines of this:

```
Array.prototype.appendStringToElementAtIndex = function(index, str) {
    if(typeof this[index] === 'undefined' || typeof this[index] !== 'string') return false;
    this[index] += ' ' + str;
};


myArr = ["val0a", "val1a", "val2a"];
myArr.appendStringToElementAtIndex(1, "val1b");

console.log(myArr.join(', ')); //val0a, val1a val1b, val2a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myArr.push(myArr[myArr.length - 1].split(" ").push("val42").join(" "));  // even
```

Answer (score 0):

to append a value to an element of an array you can just do this:

```
myArr = ["val0a", "val1a", "val2a"... "val600a"];
indexToAppendTo = 2;
val2 = "val2b"
myArr[ indexToAppendTo ] += (" " + val2) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

To concatenate to an element that's a string:

```
myArr[2] = myArr[2] += 'blah';
```

To reassign it:

```
myArr[2] = 'foo';
```